# riddle - pray you can find the word!

Tags: riddle, word

To answer this riddle, solve each of the four lines independently and put all the clues together to get a one-word final answer.

*Nonsensical abstraction high up in the army; 

The woman with the wheel fires the cannon. 

She's very fast but only in reverse gear. 

Certainly a terrorist, but only just starting.*

**Hint for non-mathematicians:**

> First line: [Category Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_nonsense)

Comment: [This chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18793/alternatives) seems to have turned into a discussion room for this question, if anyone wants to join in or get hints.

Comment: Well the clue does sort of imply that it's one word... that might be something

Comment: [Please don't change your question after the fact](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions).

Comment: @Gilles - You suggest improvements and then say I shouldn't change my question???

Comment: @randal'thor I suggested improvements to get the answer that you intended. That would make a **different** question, since it would have different answers.

Comment: @Gilles - Did you bother reading the *answer* to that meta question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EXPLANATION FOLLOWED BY CONCLUSION**

Nonsensical abstraction high up in the army;

> "general abstract nonsense" - Possibly meaning that the lines are not to be taken as talking about the same thing. But rather that they are to be linked at a later time - i.e. that things here are not going to be strongly semantically or syntactically coupled. In general though, this line yields "**CAT**EGORY THEORY".

The woman with the wheel fires the cannon.

> St. Catherine of the Wheel (Catherine of Alexandria) was tortured and executed on a wheel. She is part of the Christian Canon (homophone of "Cannon") - "firing" may refer to inspiring vitality or possibly as in "firing clay in a kiln" (as in cementing). Regardles, this line yields "ST **CAT**HERINE".

She's very fast but only in reverse gear.

> She is the fastest thing there is - Tachyon. So, she's in reverse gear - "NOYH**CAT**"

Certainly a terrorist, but only just starting.

> **C**ertainly **A** **T**errorist. Lynch mob, anyone?

**The title**
pray you can find the word!

> This refers to very popular [riddle recently by avigrail](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4615/are-you-clever-enough-you-will-have-to-pray). There it referred to "prey" (as a homophone) because we're looking for a predator.

What word am I getting at here?

There only coherent thread I can tie between them all is:

> CAT

Comment: Well done for finding the St. Catherine reference! But that's the only religious reference (the title is just meant to refer to one of avi's riddles). You're nearly there...

Comment: Little-known fact: actually Joan of Arc was burnt at the stake for wearing men's clothes. I jest not! Anyway she's nothing to do with this riddle.

Comment: I don't understand what you're doing with the third line. If you want to work Joan of Arc into it, “reverse gear” is inappropriate clothes (one of the charges against her was wearing men's clothes), and “very fast” refers to how steadfast her convictions were. Several words like *torture* and *martyr*, *execution* fit the last three lines, but I don't see how they reconcile with the first line. Also, you don't address how Saint Catherine (nice find!) *fires* the cannon: she wasn't the first saint.

Comment: @Gilles - 'Fires' wasn't supposed to signify anything; I just needed to link 'woman', 'wheel', and 'cannon' into something coherent. PS: nice to see you're getting into riddles too :-)

Comment: @randal'thor Hi rand :D But the interpretation of canon is fine then?

Comment: @d'alar'cop - Yep, 'canon' is just supposed to mean 'saint' and St. Catherine is the answer to the second line.

Comment: @randal'thor The riddle is missing something that says “take the beginnings of words”. You could do it in the framing question; “getting at” could be interpreted to convey the *end* of words, but not the beginning. There's also the typo in *canon*, the business with “fires” not being justified, as well as “how to prove”. So I'm afraid your intended solution is not a good fit for the riddle as posted.

Comment: @Gilles homophones are something to always be on the look for, so "cannon" vs. canon is OK in my opinion

Comment: but something like "certainly a terrorist _initially_" would be nice

Comment: and how about this as second line , "the woman with the wheel sounds like part of the cannon"

Comment: @Gilles - I think "cannon" is OK as it stands, but you have a point for the last line.

Comment: Perhaps I should also put in something about the general solution method (each line gives you SOMETHING, spot a common strand in those SOMETHINGs to get the answer)?

Comment: @randal'thor “Hear the woman with the wheel fired by the cannon”, maybe? And for the last line ”Certainly a terrorist, if you shift the blame“. Then a framing question like “What word started it all?” (perhaps too obvious).

Comment: @Gilles your suggestion is great! thanks for the constructive help :D

Comment: @Gilles It seems you were disappointed, that's unfortunate. Is this example more satisfactory? http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5428/riddle-pray-that-this-is-the-last-one

Answer (score 5):

The answer has to be

> Sarah Palin, in a parallel world where she became President of the United States.

First let's cover the basics. The “woman with the wheel” is the person who drives the country, i.e. the person at the very top. She's the head of the armed forces (“high up in the army”). We're told that she “fires the cannon”, i.e. she launches the country's weapons by herself (or at least she presses the button — other people load the cannon for her); this must refer to the atomic bomb, as other weapons are fired entirely by underlings.

So far we have the gender and position, which still leaves quite a few possibilities. We have to use the rest of the riddle to figure out who it is. The start of the riddle is a big clue: it's an “abstraction”, so this is about a fictional world! Furthermore, it's a “nonsensical” one, i.e. a counterfactual one: an alternate world where history proceeded differently.

We have a woman who's “fast”. This could be interpreted in several ways. A common meaning is one who sleeps around, but among politicians, sleeping around is far more common with men than with women. So “fast” must refer to another meaning of the word — tenacious, resistant, not fading with age. I can think of several women who came close to becoming head of state and who fit this description, so we'll need the rest of the riddle to whittle the field down to one.

“Only in reverse gear” means that she is by no means a progressive, i.e. she is a staunch conservative. This rules out, in particular, Hillary Clinton and Ségolène Royal. As for Sarah Palin, she fits the clues like a glove. She was a basketball [point guard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_guard), which is a clever double meaning for the second line — the point guard passes the ball (fires the cannon) to other players, and decides which player to pass it to based on tactical considerations (hence acting as a wheel on which the ball turns).

In the final line, “terrorist” means not one who is directly violent, but one who supports a policy of scaremongering, as was the case in the US following 9-11. “How to prove it?” Her opponents were unsuccessful in demonstrating to the American public that her policies were overly strong, which is why she got elected.

The injunction to “pray” and “find the word” in the title alludes to her being Christian, which is a religion of the Word.

> The “abstract nonsense” hint refers to category theory. Why point non-mathematicians at category theory? They'll have no idea what it means. “Category theory” here is thus not about the algebraic concept, but rather concerns the everyday meaning of the word “category” — the puzzle looks like math, but that's only for the surface reading, and the answer lies in another category.

I do remain puzzled by the question calling for a *word* rather than a name. Could this be a nickname? I can't find one that matches the clues.

Comment: Wow! This is an imaginative answer, but completely different from what I intended. My knowledge of politics is so tiny that I can't tell how well this fits the riddle, but I'll take your word for it and +1.

Comment: Only issue here would is the "what word am I getting at here". Unless that is a mistake we should assume the answer is a single word. Brilliant answer +1

Comment: I like "only in reverse gear" meaning she's quick to start damage control when her mouth runs away with her, with a  common term being "back-pedaling" :P

Comment: @Oblongamous - I've just [solved another riddle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5267/oh-it-is-greater-than-god) in less than 1 minute, but I just get nothing instead of a shallot sandwich! :-(

Comment: Surely that is the epitome of dissapointment :)

Comment: @Oblongamous - Yes, the answer is meant to be a single word. For a moment I was worried there was more than one correct answer, but I knew there must be *something* that didn't fit with this answer!

Comment: @Oblongamous Ah, good point about single word. That would have to be *president*, unless Sarah Palin has a nickname that I'm unaware of. Perhaps she only got that nickname in the alternate universe, but then I don't see how the clues point to a specific nickname.

Comment: @Gilles - The clues don't point to any nickname for Sarah Palin. You're barking up the wrong tree, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Gilles It's been cracked. Join the lynch mob?

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete solution, but maybe it can help someone else see what I'm missing.

The lines look like

> cryptic crossword clues

to me. Especially since the link in your hint refers to

> **General** abstract nonsense.

With "high up in the army" pointing to

> general.

Also, "the woman with the wheel" is probably referring to

> a ship (ships are usually referred to with female pronouns in English and ships have wheels/helms)

With the "firing the canon part", can the actual word that solves the second line be

> artillery?

Comment: Interesting idea, but d'alar'cop has already cracked the second line, and your typo 'canon' is actually correct!

Comment: @randal'thor My bad. Saw your comment after I posted. Nice riddle btw. Very meta.

Comment: Thanks! :-) I've posted another one [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5396/multi-part-challenge-riddles-and-cipher) if you're still hungry for riddles.