# I am evil, I am good; What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am evil, I am good
>
> I am nothing, but higher than everything
>
> I cannot be found, but I am everywhere
>
> I am the whole of all things
>
> There is nothing else like me

What am I?

Comment: Universe maybe?

Comment: it's in the hint:  I'm nothing

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5267/oh-it-is-greater-than-god?

Comment: @QuestionAsker no, the answer as chosen is zero not nothing (there is a difference, mainly mathmatical)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be

> Null?  Null can represent multiple values even oposites simultaniously such as true and false or 'evil' and 'good'

Because

> Null can represent 0 or 'nothing', but is lower and higher than everything

Not sure about "I cannot be found, but I am everywhere"

I am the whole of all things

> Null can represent infinity or objects which could be pretty much anything

There is nothing else like me

> I can think of a few actually but I suppose they'd basically just be Null by another name

Answer (score 2):

The answer should be

> God.

Because

> God cannot be found, but He is everywhere.

Comment: Please use spoilers with `>!`.

Answer (score 2):

Could it be:

> The Void.

Because:

>   1. A Void is neither Good or Evil.
>
>   2. It's technically 'nothing' as it is just empty space, but has a meaning to our universe.
>
>   3. It can't be defined itself, as it can't be found, touched, or tested, however we know it's there.
>
>   4. Let's be honest, There is nothing else like it.