# You can't see me, yet I'm there

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> You can't see me, yet I'm there
>   Under blue or red, white or black
>
> I decide if you will live
>   I can put you to sleep
>
> I'm with you, as you can see
>   Whether home, on space or sea
>
> There's no use running free
>   I will drag you back to me
>
> Don't try poisoning me, it's pointless
>   You'll be rendering your life useless
>
> I can harm you, I can kill thee
>   Yet you crave me and you seek me

## Who/what am I?

Hint 1:

> We've been through with each other

Hint 2:

> It was you who started the fire, I just kept it alive

Comment: This is starting to seem really broad with all the potential answers....

Comment: I think I'll start adding hints to avoid the vagueness

Comment: Hint 2 implies the answer is Billy Joel :)

Comment: I did write that hint with the song in mind, so you're not completely wrong ;)

Comment: I still have no idea (everything I've come up with has been suggested as answers already). Following until an answer is accepted which is hopefully satisfying.

Comment: There is always the possibility that someone got it right, but without writing a satisfactory answer ;)

Comment: @HugoBDesigner A correct but not yet satisfactory answer may not (yet) warrant the $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$; but it's generally a good idea to let the answerer know they've got it except for some polishing of the details - otherwise we just keep getting new (and usually increasingly desperate) answers as none of the existing ones has been acknowledged as being (nearly) correct.

Comment: @Rubio Thanks! Perhaps I wasn't so forward with letting them know they got it right, but I did show them what they got wrong so they could improve their answer. It's almost at a point I'd be happy with accepting

Comment: The only other path I was following was since it says "home, *on* space, or sea" [C], I was deeply searching for a way to make 'keyboard' part of the clue.

Comment: First **unclosed as too broad**question i saw that has so many answers +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you

> Air?

EDIT: fixing my answer

You can't see me, yet I'm there
Under blue or red, white or black

> Under the sky: clear skies are blue, sunsets are red, cloudy skies are white, and nighttime is black. credit goes to @TheSpartan

I decide if you will live
I can put you to sleep

> Air is necessary for life; Low air pressure or excessive carbon dioxide can make you drowsy

I'm with you, as you can see
Whether home, on space or sea

> It's used in tanks for sea and space exploration

There's no use running free
I will drag you back to me

> Running through it creates drag (air friction/resistance)

Don't try poisoning me, it's pointless
You'll be rendering your life useless

> If you poison the air around you, you are putting yourself at risk too

I can harm you, I can kill thee
Yet you crave me and you seek me

> Gasses in air can be poisonous, even deadly, but some are necessary for life

**HINTS:**

Hint 1:

> We've been through with each other - You go through air, and air goes through you (your lungs)

Hint 2:

> It was you who started the fire, I just kept it alive - The oxygen in air is necessary to keep it alive

Comment: This is a good answer, but try to address the other parts of the riddle okay?

Comment: You seem to mix up gasses and air a fair bit. Air is a mixture of gasses, and a gas is not necessarily considered air

Comment: i think it works because air is always comprised of gasses, but i can be clearer

Comment: You got some of the lines incorrectly, more specifically the following: "Under blue or red, white or black": the "Under" is very deliberate. "Whether home, on space or sea": air is not everywhere on an "elementary" level, but think about why it would be in these two places with you. "There's no use running free I will drag you back to me": "running free" and "drag" are also very deliberate word choices ;)

Comment: You got almost everything right, with the sole exception of the "Under blue or red, white or black" segment

Comment: "Under blue or red, white or black" -> how about a cloudless sky (blue), sunset (red), cloudy sky (white), and the night sky (black)?

Comment: ahh, i think you did it @TheSpartan

Comment: I've edited the answer in order to accept it, as well as some formatting :)

Answer (score 6):

Conspiracy theory:

> The US Government

You can't see me, yet I'm there : Under blue or red, white or black

> The voting states are either blue or red, the voters are [mostly white or black](https://www.census.gov/content/dam/Census/newsroom/press-kits/2017/voting-and-registration/figure03.png)

I decide if you will live // I can put you to sleep

> The government can decide if you live, it can put you to sleep by with the [death penalty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_punishment_by_the_United_States_federal_government).

I'm with you, as you can see // Whether home, on space or sea

> It has a presence everywhere; federal regulations apply to things in your home, satellites in space, and its navy travels the seven seas.

Don't try poisoning me, it's pointless // You'll be rendering your life useless

> Treason, maybe? Maybe, possibly, this refers to the idea that without government Anarchy and Chaos would reign.

I can harm you, I can kill thee // Yet you crave me and you seek me

> Harm? Check. Kill? Check. Yet we need roads and military and schools and the FDA, etc. etc.

Comment: Hah, very creative! Unfortunately, not the answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Are you

> Gravity? Because gravity cannot be seen under normal light, a black light and obviously not red or blue. Gravity can also put you to sleep with G-force knocking pilots out when making tight turns. Gravity is everywhere, including home, in space or at sea. Gravity can almost always pull you back down hence "what comes up must come down". Gravity isn't a living thing meaning you cant kill it with poison. Gravity can harm you or even kill you if you fall from high enough and the new space race means that lots of rich people are clambering to get to other planets with their own gravity.

Comment: Interesting and original answer! Welcome to Puzzling SE!

Comment: Interesting answer, but not the one I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Oxygen? Oxygen can't be seen, but you can make it into different colors by releasing those colored fog machine (although that's not changing oxygen's color). You can't live without oxygen, and Nitrogen Dioxide (aka laughing gas) is a sedative used in dentistry. Oxygen is everywhere breathable oxygen (O2), water (H2O) and oxygen compounds/isolated oxygen in space (though not very much). You can't run from oxygen, you'll always try to breathe it back in, Try to Poison oxygen (say with carbon dioxide) you hurt yourself, and oxygen in different forms are harmful (also oxygen is fuel for fire) but under asphyxiation of any form, you try to breathe oxygen in.

Comment: i understand the red and blue part as it is the commonly used color to represent oxygen and nitrogen, but the black and white part is for hydrogen and carbon in this case, so maybe just air ? quite puzzling

Comment: Techinically though there is no "air" in space or the sea....

Comment: I've updated the riddle to clear out the misconception about the colors

Comment: @North well you technically *need* air in space and in the sea...

Answer (score 1):

Are you a..

> A Dream?

```
You can't see me, yet I'm there
Under blue or red, white or black
```

> [You don't see a dream, you dream it. LOL. But it will always be there. Under black or white skin, under red or blue veins, tucked neatly in your brain.]

```
I decide if you will live
I can put you to sleep
```

> [Dreams are what helps us sleep, keep us dreaming for it. They can also end lives, motivations once broken]

```
I'm with you, as you can see
Whether home, on space or sea
```

> [Dreams are always with you, wherever you go. They are a part of what is human.]

```
There's no use running free
I will drag you back to me
```

> [There will always be times one will turn back on a dream but everytime, there will be an opportunity that could present itself to go back to it and pursue it.]

```
Don't try poisoning me, it's pointless
You'll be rendering your life useless
```

> [Like in the 2nd stanza, if you kill a dream, it could very well end you (spiritually, mentally)]

```
I can harm you, I can kill thee
Yet you crave me and you seek me
```

> [Similar to 2nd and 5th stanze, broken dreams can end you. But we will always seek them.]

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the correct answer :D

Comment: Very interesting approach, but not the answer I'm looking for :)

Comment: @HugoBDesigner Interesting. I am much looking forward to seeing the correct answer. But I think the colors explanation was very nice for this answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer whilst I think about it more

Are you

> Your subconscious mind?

You can't see me, yet I'm there
 Under blue or red, white or black

> It's always there, no matter what

I decide if you will live
 I can put you to sleep

> Your subconscious makes a lot of your decisions, for example when you're tired.

I'm with you, as you can see
 Whether home, on space or sea

> It doesn't matter where you are, you always have it

There's no use running free
 I will drag you back to me

> Trying to ignore it won't work

Don't try poisoning me, it's pointless
 You'll be rendering your life useless

> ????

I can harm you, I can kill thee
 Yet you crave me and you seek me

> ?????

Comment: Clever answer, but not the one I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is

> Time.

You can't see me, yet I'm there // Under blue or red, white or black

> We can't actually see the time (as a physical entity).

I decide if you will live // I can put you to sleep

> As we say - Time decides when you will die. We see time before going to sleep.

I'm with you, as you can see // Whether home, on space or sea

> Time is everywhere, the 4th dimension.

Don't try poisoning me, it's pointless // You'll be rendering your life useless

> You cannot change the time (your past etc.), its useless.

I can harm you, I can kill thee // Yet you crave me and you seek me

> We all have bad times but still we keep on living.

*PS: This is my first ever answer on Puzzling.*

Comment: Nice work, but not the answer I'm looking for. The colors are also part of the puzzle ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is a long shot, but I think the answer is

> Vision

```
You can't see me, yet I'm there
Under blue or red, white or black
```

> You can't see a vision, but you have it regarding your eyes color.

```
I decide if you will live
I can put you to sleep
```

> You can see the danger and run away from it. Thus you live. Close your eyes and you'll sleep.

```
I'm with you, as you can see
Whether home, on space or sea
```

> You always have your vision with you. As you can see ;).

```
There's no use running free
I will drag you back to me
```

> You can't run free without seeing. You'll have to open your eyes to get the vision of where you're going.

```
Don't try poisoning me, it's pointless
You'll be rendering your life useless
```

> Poison your eyes and you'll be blind. I am not so sure about useless though.

```
I can harm you, I can kill thee
Yet you crave me and you seek me
```

> Don't have much for this currently.

Comment: Interesting perspective, but not the answer I'm looking for :)

Comment: Oh well, it doesn't harm to try :p

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer:

> Your Mood?

```
You can't see me, yet I'm there
Under blue or red, white or black
```

> Mood is an intangible thing; the colors are reference to a mood ring

```
I decide if you will live
I can put you to sleep
```

> Your mood sets your emotions, bad/depressed moods make you tired

```
I'm with you, as you can see
Whether home, on space or sea
```

> Your mood is an innate part of you

```
There's no use running free
I will drag you back to me
```

> Reference to being 'stuck in a mood'

```
Don't try poisoning me, it's pointless
You'll be rendering your life useless
```

> When you 'poison the mood' you make things miserable for yourself and everyone around you

```
I can harm you, I can kill thee
Yet you crave me and you seek me
```

> A persistent negative mood can be painful and even lead to suicide, but we are always striving to be in a good mood

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer:

> God

You can't see me, yet I'm there
Under blue or red, white or black

> God is always here, but we can see Him through His works. America (red and blue flag) was founded as one nation under God over all people.

I decide if you will live
I can put you to sleep

> Yep!

I'm with you, as you can see
Whether home, on space or sea

> God is always here.

There's no use running free
I will drag you back to me

> You cannot run from God.

Don't try poisoning me, it's pointless
You'll be rendering your life useless

> God is all-powerful.

I can harm you, I can kill thee
Yet you crave me and you seek me

> Yep, and we crave and seek to know the Lord.

Comment: Many atheist don't seek the Lord, nor do people of different beliefs besides Christianity.

Comment: Also I believe God does not "drag" anybody to him...

Comment: I may have the incorrect answer to the riddle, but I do believe people outside of Christianity seek God (i.e. Judaism, Islam, etc.). I also believe God can draw us to Him (John 6:44), drag might not be the right word, but I was just Trying to make it fit! :P

Comment: I don't know if trying to put Biblical stuff into something like this is appropriate. "Trying to make it fit" isn't a criteria in puzzling, and stretching riddles so it fits your solution is counter-intuitive when solving riddles (the solution should fit nicely.

Comment: First thing that came to my mind was John Cena.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Drugs (Pills)

You can't see me, yet I'm there

> You cant actually see drugs as they are inside the pills

Under blue or red, white or black

> Pills can be many colours

I decide if you will live

> They can kill you if you have too many

I can put you to sleep

> They can also put you to sleep

I'm with you, as you can see

> They are inside your body once ingested

Whether home, on space or sea

> Home space or sea

There's no use running free
I will drag you back to me

> Drugs are addictive

Don't try poisoning me, it's pointless
You'll be rendering your life useless

> If you poison drugs they will just kill you

I can harm you, I can kill thee
Yet you crave me and you seek me

> They can kill you but they are addictive so you cannot stop taking them

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> Nitrogen?

`You can't see me, yet I'm there
Under blue or red, white or black`

> Nitrogen makes up 78% of the air we breathe. It is one of the primary gasses in reflecting light in the atmosphere - showing us a blue sky, or a red sky depening on angle of viewing. The Nitrogen is still there even when we can't see the sky, for example under white clouds, or a black night sky.

`I decide if you will live
I can put you to sleep`

> We need nitrogen to live. If we don't have nitrogen in our bodies, amino acids cant function properly. Muscles deteriorate. We get sick, then we will cease to be. Nitrous oxide is used as a general anaesthetic which is used to "put you to sleep" when undergoing surgery.

`I'm with you, as you can see
Whether home, on space or sea`

> Nitrogen is everywhere. Nitrogen is part of the cholorophyll in plants on our planet. Scientists have discovered clouds of nitrogen in space. Nitrogen is also in the sea due to the nitrification process.

`There's no use running free
I will drag you back to me`

> There is no escape from nitrogen. Hah. Decompression sickness can occur if you try to rise from a deep dive too quick. Thus if you ascend too fast, you need to go back down to decompress at the correct rate and let the gasses release from your body at the correct rate. This is pretty weak though.

`Don't try poisoning me, it's pointless
You'll be rendering your life useless`

> Grasping at straws now... Nitrogen Dioxide is harmful (NO2, Nitrogen "poisoned" with Oxygen). It can cause respiratory problems, which you know... can lead to death. It can also cause reproductive problems I think, which to some might render their life useless.

`I can harm you, I can kill thee
Yet you crave me and you seek me`

> Not enough Nitrogen can harm you, too much nitrogen can kill you. We need nitrogen, and seek it through the air we breathe. Alternative: Nitrous Oxide is a popular recreational drug, and incorrect use can result in death. But party goers want to get the short lived high and still seek N2O even when given the associated health risks.

Answer (score 1):

You could be

> Heart (Love)

```
You can't see me, yet I'm there
Under blue or red, white or black
```

> You cannot see your own heart, yet we all have one, despite color or ethnicity

```
I decide if you will live
I can put you to sleep
```

> The heart is responsible for sustaining your life. It can also put you to "sleep" in cases of heart attacks for example. Also, as the heart is the universal symbol of love, "sleep" could easily be translated as the hypnotic feeling of being in love, falling under the spell of a significant other.

```
I'm with you, as you can see
Whether home, on space or sea
```

> Your heart is always with you, and you always keep thinking of your loved ones, whether you are by them, or traveling without.

```
There's no use running free
I will drag you back to me
```

> Even if you get heartbroken, most of the times you still try to get back with that person. You can't help it, it just happens, defying logic.

```
Don't try poisoning me, it's pointless
You'll be rendering your life useless
```

> Literally poisoning your heart would end your life. Metaphorically speaking, poisoning your relationship or your own feelings would get you depressed and behaving in a bad mood, resulting in having no joy in life (and what is life without joy other than useless?).

```
I can harm you, I can kill thee
Yet you crave me and you seek me
```

> As it is possibly the most vital organ for keeping you alive aside the brain, any mishap of the heart could harm you or kill you. Yet, we all crave happiness from love and seek to be loved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this riddle requires certain knowledge to solve, still I will give it a try.

I guess you are

> [Copper conductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copper_conductor) (copper wire)

You can't see me, yet I'm there

> We usually can't see copper wires, since it is either covered with plastic jacket or built inside the concrete wall with jackets.

Under blue or red, white or black

> Here comes the vital part: [electrical wiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_wiring#Colour_coding_of_wiring_by_region) (wiring color code).
>  
>  We sometimes may found more thinner wires with different colors inside a normal wire. These colors refers to different kinds of cable, such as *neutral*, *ground* and different *phases* from 2-phase/3-phase power. From the link above, blue, red, white and black are applied to wiring by different countries.
>  
>  For the most obvious example, check Brazil's fixed cable color code.
>  
>  (OP is from Brazil :D)

I decide if you will live

I can put you to sleep

> Copper wire bring electricity to machines, which may capable to decide if someone will live (life support system such as [ECMO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extracorporeal_membrane_oxygenation)) or fall asleep (some kind of smart appliances like Nest thermostat?).

I'm with you, as you can see

Whether home, on space or sea

> Though copper wire is rarely seen under plastic jacket, we always knew the existence of those electrical wire, whether at home, inside the space station, or under the sea.

There's no use running free

I will drag you back to me

> Many people can't live without electricity nowdays, especially a living place without any electrical infrastructure.

Don't try poisoning me, it's pointless

You'll be rendering your life useless

> Not sure about this part, poisoning cable sounds unreasonable. Yet, I am sure that those who throw any liquid on it may get a electric shock.

I can harm you, I can kill thee

Yet you crave me and you seek me

> I think it is refer to electricity than copper wire itself. Electricity can harm, even kill me, but I need them to post on Puzzling!

Hint 1

> "We've been through with each other"
>  
>  Well, we surely been through about 200+ years.

Hint 2

> "It was you who started the fire, I just kept it alive"
>  
>  Wires doesn't produce electricity itself, they transfer electricity to make sure it won't vanish on the half way to the destination.

Answer (score 1):

Is the Answer

> Hope?That is what i concluded from the hint. 
>  
>  Our hopes were there with us throught. Say we sought something in our mind (It was you who started the fire) but it is kept alive by our hopes (I just kept it alive) because we hope for a thing. 
>  
>  We can't see our hopes yet they are there. Whether under broad day light or night or under any other mood we hope for things to happen(blue and red can be considered as different moods of a person where blue represent calmness and red as alertness/danger/angry etc a person hopes under different moods). 
>  
>  Our hopes decide if we live as poisonous hopes can lead a person to end up life i.e. when they become hopeless. Regarding the line which says that I can put you to sleep, it can be considered as at night a person can fall asleep all the way while hoping for something. 
>  
>  Our hopes are with us all the way through, whether at home or whether we are in sea or space. No matter how hard we try not to hope , we end up hoping for something or the other in any situation in life i.e. we are pulled towards our hopes or vice versa. 
>  
>  If we poison our hopes or in other words having false hopes can make us have a tough time in life. As said earlier our own hopes can harm us and even kill us (if a person goes hopeless in life (!SUICIDE!) which we usually see happening in case when a person ends up his/her life because they become hopeless due to any kind of situation whether money problems,family problem or any other crises). Yet a person does not stop "hoping". 
>  
>  We always end up hoping. :)

Comment: @Shane Hsu what did you meant be completing the incomplete spoilers ?

Comment: The markup for a spoiler tag is `>!`, you wrote `>`. Welcome to Puzzling.SE! This is very well-detailed for a first answer, I hope you stick around.

Comment: @F1Krazy Thanks for the tip. Will remember that while answering any further questions. And yes will stick around HOPEFULLY, till my brain haggles around all those puzzles out there :)..

Comment: any thoughts regarding my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are

> The sun

You can't see me, yet I'm there

> Looking directly into the sun is not something someone does

Under blue or red, white or black

> The air, in daylight, can appear to be blue, when the sub sets it might be red. Clouds might let the sky appear white and if the sun sets completely there is blackness.

I decide if you will live

> We would not survive without the sun. And some places on earth might be to cold or dry to live, this all depends on the earth's axis

I can put you to sleep

> We sleep at night, when the sun has set

I'm with you, as you can see

> The sun is always there

Whether home, on space or sea

> The sun can be seem from everywhere

There's no use running free
I will drag you back to me

> I believe this revers to the gravitational pull the sun has on the earth

Don't try poisoning me, it's pointless
You'll be rendering your life useless

> We need the sun...

I can harm you, I can kill thee
Yet you crave me and you seek me

> This might refer to nasty things like sunburns and skin cancer. and now matter how bad those things might be, we will always seek out the sun for our own pleasure.

Comment: Very interesting answer and surprisingly fitting! Unfortunately, not the answer I was looking for, but you did get one of the hints right :P

Answer (score 0):

### HERE GOES NOTHING

I think the answer is

> A sadistic girlfriend who just happens to be invisible.

You can't see me, yet I'm there // Under blue or red, white or black

> She's invisible, but she's still there. Under a blue sky, white clouds, black hair or red hair? lol

I decide if you will live // I can put you to sleep

> Well like, if she wants to kill you, you're pretty screwed. And obviously she can put you to sleep like any other girlfriend...

I'm with you, as you can see // Whether home, on space or sea

> If you really like her and vice versa, I suppose she'll always be with you...even if you go to space?

Don't try poisoning me, it's pointless // You'll be rendering your life useless

> If you poison her, you're going to go to jail for the rest of your life, which will probably make it useless.

I can harm you, I can kill thee // Yet you crave me and you seek me

> Yeah she's sadistic so she always thinks about harming and killing you...too bad so sad. And you crave her and seek her? Sounds highly suggestive...

Probably not the best answer here, but like YOLO!

Comment: That raises the question, how does one go to jail for killing an invisible person? Where's the evidence? :P

Comment: LOL you got me there. It's okay; I'll try and think of something else.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is ................

> Nothing.

The reasoning?

This riddle, similar to its original variation (unless i'm dreadfully wrong), is simply a wordplay. Replace the 'thing' in question with the word 'Nothing' and each statement playfully comes to life.

To recap, the version i remembered hearing was:

"I am Greater than heaven,

I am lower than Hell,

Rich People Want me,

Poor People Have me,

If you eat me,

You will die.

What am i?"

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!  Could you add some details to your answer about how you came to this conclusion?  Answers without explanation are sometimes marked for deletion.

Comment: Hi puzzledpig, 

 ive heard a similar riddle before and im sure this riddle is the same in that only one answer suffices. In this case the word i have stated. Hope this prevents deletion

Comment: Could you explain though? In more detail?

Comment: I take it you're talking about [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5267/oh-it-is-greater-than-god)?

Comment: Haha Yup. That's the one. Not sure if i'm right about it being the same though. Would have to wait on Hugo's response

Comment: I don't believe they're the same riddle, and neither does anyone else from the looks of things, otherwise the question would have been flagged as a duplicate. I don't see too many similarities between them.