# Today I give you a mathematical pleasure, which you might want to take up and measure (What am I?)

Tags: riddle, mathematics, knowledge, poetry

Today I give you a mathematical pleasure,

which you might want to take up and measure.

With a pole, or a hole, oh well,

you might want to read up on Borel.

My spirit can always be found in myself,

not somewhere else way up on a shelf.

With cups and caps you can bet,

that I'm nothing more than a well-equipped set.

---

Hint 1

> No calculations, just math [knowledge](/questions/tagged/knowledge).

Hint 2

> A hole or a pole is an allusion to topological spaces.

Hint 3

> Let's just say that BSA, is not bovine serum albumin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are, specifically,

> the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on a topological space.

(Iterations of this answer:

> I got immediately the general theme, but I put **$\sigma$-algebra** at first, then changed to **topological space** after the second hint was added, then finally put them together in the intended way after the third hint.)

---

*Today I give you a mathematical pleasure,

which you might want to take up and measure.*

> Every topological space can be turned into a measurable space by using the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

*With a pole, or a hole, oh well,*

> Topology is about deformation of objects, but a hole cannot be deformed away.

*you might want to read up on Borel.*

> Borel sets again.

*My spirit can always be found in myself,

not somewhere else way up on a shelf.*

> A topology on a set contains the set itself as one of its elements, and so does a $\sigma$-algebra.

*With cups and caps you can bet,

that I'm nothing more than a well-equipped set.*

> A topology is closed under certain kinds of union and intersection (cup and cap), and it's simply something that a set can be equipped with. Same for a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: V jnf guvaxvat bs n Obery fcnpr nf gur nafjre (onfvpnyyl gur fnzr guvat), ohg V pna'g cynpr gur ubyrf naq cbyrf guvat. Vg'f znxvat zr guvax bs mrebrf naq cbyrf bs pbzcyrk shapgvbaf, ohg V pna'g chg gung pyhr vagb vg.

Comment: You're so close! The thing you mention as the answer is not necessarily closed under intersection. I've added a hint.

Comment: @Galen OK, edited to a new answer. (I actually thought of this first - I know topology much better than measure theory - but then the mention of Borel sent me in the other direction.)

Comment: You were half right the first time, now you're half right again. Put them together, and you'll be okay then.

Comment: @Galen A topological measure space then?

Comment: There's a name for it :P

Comment: I added a hint!

Comment: YUS! You got it! I am so gratified! Thank you for trying my riddle!

Comment: @Galen Thank you for making a mathematical riddle! Btw, you might like [this one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/5019/5373) (shameless plug).